# Does "text selection mode" work the same for all views & devices

Tags: android, android-emulator, textselection

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#emulateShiftHeld%28%29) for WebView.emulateShiftHeld() says:

> Use this method to put the WebView
>   into text selection mode. Do not rely
>   on this functionality; it will be
>   deprecated in the future.

What does "put the WebView into **text selection mode**" mean?

To clarify:

1. Does "text selection mode" work
   the same for WebView as in other
   **views**?
2. Does "text selection mode" work
   the same on the emulator as in
   other, **real**, devices?

On the emulator, for example, I tie the function to a menu item, and when I select that item (on the emulator), and start dragging the mouse over some text, I have 2 fat cursors ("handles"?) marking the beginning the start & end of the selection. When I click the end "hand", I receive a pop-up balloon saying "Text copied to clipboard".

Comment: pls give me some detail how you able to put webview in to text selection mode. im struggling with it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "put the WebView into text selection mode" mean?

> > > Your WebView translate into selection mode. Which enables uses to copy text into clipboard. Latter he might paste to pate in some editors.

To clarify:

1. Does "text selection mode" work the same for WebView as in other views?
2. Does "text selection mode" work the same on the emulator as in other, real, devices?

> > > > Expect WebView other Views doesn't support "Text selection".