# How to select text from a webview and not copy it?

Tags: android

I am creating an application which requires a webview.

I want to enable text selection in webview. (I found a few solutions but none of them worked)

Once the webview is selected, it should not be directly copied. I should be able to expand the selection range with handles (It is possible in version 2.3 and later. But I want this on versions lower than 2.3. HTC's browser gives us this option)

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to select texts from webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview)

Comment: Solution which you have accepted that doesn't work on ICS

Comment: On ICS, it is handled by the OS itself. You need not do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recently i solved that

put this function on create or on load in activity

```
private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view)
{
    try
    {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
    }
}
```

it will done...

Comment: ok i got it to work... now there is a second part to the question i asked. how can i select the range of text to be selected on android 2.2?