# Get Selected Text of WebView

Tags: android, webview, getselection

I want to get the selected text from webview so for that I get some of the projects from github but that all are not proper as I want.

This are the links.

- https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection.
- https://github.com/bossturbo/WebViewMarker

So can you please tell me the proper way to get the selected text from it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6147929

Comment: By that I can select a text , but i am not getting the selected text

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to select texts from webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview)

Comment: Can you please give me the example by that i can get that , yeah by that way i can get a selected text. i gone though your link but there is no code to get selected text.