# Webview text selection not clearing

Tags: android, webview, selection, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

I have implemented an `ActionMode.Callback` for custom text selection functions within a `WebView`. The problem that I am having is that the selection and the action mode states do not match.

When I long-press, everything starts out just fine.

[image: Upon long-press, selection highlight appears along with the contextual action bar.]

When I interact with one of the buttons, or the `WebView` (excluding the actual selection) then the `ActionMode` should be destroyed, and the selection should disappear.

[image: Selecting a button, or touching outside the selection area.]
[image: The CAB should close, and the selection should disappear.]

In Android 4.4, KitKat, this is exactly what happens.

---

However, this is not what is happening in 4.1.1 - 4.3, Jelly Bean. When I click one of the buttons, the selection is not removed.

[image: Tap a button from the contextual action bar.]
[image: After tapping a button, the selection remains.]

When I tap outside the selection, just the opposite happens. The selection is removed, but the contextual action bar remains on the screen.

[image: Tapping the <code>WebView</code> after the selection starts.]
[image: The selection is cleared, but the contextual action bar remains.]

---

Here is the code for my `CustomWebView`

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
        ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
        return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown.
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // This method is called when the handlebars are moved.
            loadJavascript("javascript:getSelectedTextInfo()");
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId() {
            case R.id.button_1:
                // do stuff
                break;
            ...
            default:
                break;
            }

            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO This does not work in Jelly Bean (API 16 - 18; 4.1.1 - 4.3).
            clearFocus(); // Remove the selection highlight and handles.

        }
    }
}
```

As the comment above shows, I believe the problem is with the `clearFocus()` method. When I remove that method, pressing a button leaves the selection behind in 4.4, just like the behavior in Jelly Bean. `clearFocus()` gives the expected behavior in 4.4, but is not transferring to earlier APIs. (Do note that `clearFocus()` is not new to KitKat; it has been in Android since API 1.)

How can this be fixed?

Comment: me too stuck here for clearing the text selection in API 4.1.2  please anyone help me out..

Comment: @DirtyBeach how to invisible contextual bar of web view? any concept/idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After numerous attempts at solving this, I have finally got it!

The important thing to realize is that `WebView`s before Android 4.4 (KitKat) are different from your typical browser. There are a few hidden classes that come into play that start to mess up things. There's `WebViewCore` which does all the heavy lifting and actually produces results, and there's `WebViewClassic`, which is the culprit of this problem.

The solution is a semi-hack, as you don't really have to do anything to manipulate the underlying classes, but you do have to catch the problem scenarios.

`WebViewClassic` takes care of intercepting long presses and handling them for text selection, including the animation of the selection highlight and the selection handles, as well as starting the `ActionMode` that populates the Contextual Action Bar (CAB). Unfortunately, since we want to override that `ActionMode` with our own, the text selection and the CAB become out of sync, because they are not associated with each other. To solve this, keep track of your own custom `ActionMode.Callback`, **as well as** the `ActionMode.Callback` associated with the selection animation. Then, when your `ActionMode.Callback` is destroyed, call the selection's `finish()` method to destroy that `ActionMode.Callback`, as well.

OK, enough talk; here's the code.

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;
    // Add this class variable
    private ActionMode.Callback mSelectActionModeCallback;

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
        /* When running Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) or Jelly Bean (4.1 - 4.3), there
         * is a hidden class called 'WebViewClassic' that draws the selection.
         * In order to clear the selection, save the callback from Classic
         * so it can be destroyed later.
         */
        // Check the class name because WebViewClassic.SelectActionModeCallback
        // is not public API.
        String name = callback.getClass().toString();
        if (name.contains("SelectActionModeCallback")) {
            mSelectActionModeCallback = callback;
        }
        mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
        // We haven't actually done anything yet. Send our custom callback 
        // to the superclass so it will be shown on screen.
        return super.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // This is important for part 2.
            mActionMode = mode;
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown.
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // This method is called when the handlebars are moved.
            loadJavascript("javascript:getSelectedTextInfo()");
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId() {
            case R.id.button_1:
                // do stuff
                break;
            ...
            default:
                break;
            }

            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            clearFocus(); // Remove the selection highlight and handles.

            // Semi-hack in order to clear the selection
            // when running Android earlier than KitKat.
            if (mSelectActionModeCallback != null) {
                mSelectActionModeCallback.onDestroyActionMode(mode);
            }
            // Relevant to part 2.
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Believe it or not, we're only halfway finished. The above code takes care of removing the selection when the CAB closes. To close the CAB on a touch event, we have to do a little more work. This time it's much more straightforward. I use a `GestureDetector` and listen for a single tap event. When I get that event, I call `finish()` on `mActionMode` to close the CAB:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private ActionMode mActionMode; 
    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;
    private ActionMode.Callback mSelectActionModeCallback;

    // Code from above segment
    ...

    private class CustomGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                mActionMode.finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Send the event to our gesture detector
        // If it is implemented, there will be a return value
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // If the detected gesture is unimplemented, send it to the superclass
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

---

And that should do it! We did it!

You will not find the `WebViewClassic` material anywhere else; that's why I provided so much detail as to what's happening. It took many hours with the debugger to figure out what was going on. Fortunately, the `GestureDetector` class is well-documented, and includes multiple tutorials. I got my information from the [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html). I hope this helped those of you that struggled with this problem as much as I did. :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But how can i get the selected text.

Comment: loadJavascript("javascript:getSelectedTextInfo()"); is not resolvedl

Comment: `getSelectedTextInfo()` is a custom JS method that I wrote. You will need to write your own JS to access the selection. I suggest starting with `window.getSelection()`. If that does not work, try using range(s). It is also not guaranteed to work on all versions of Android; 4.0 in particular has quite a bit of JS trouble. As an alternative to the solutions provided here, please see this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection

Comment: can you give me an example of usage of getSelectedTextInfo

Comment: In my particular case, I am creating annotations (like highlights) within epubs. I use `getSelectedTextInfo()` to get the text that is selected AND its location with the DOM so I can correctly and accurately save the annotation for my users.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share some code sample. Thanks in advance