# Android copy selected text in webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to copy selected text in android WebView, I tried many methods to do this but nothing done.
like :

```
 android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
   KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0,
               KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
               KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
            shiftPressEvent.dispatch(webview);

            if(clipboard!=null)
            {
              String text = clipboard.getText().toString();
              Toast.makeText(this, "select_text_now     "+text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Many Thanks;

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview/29353049#29353049

Answer (score 1):

According to this link 
[Copy Text in a WebView in Android 2.3 and Below](http://android-ed.blogspot.in/2012/10/copy-text-in-webview-in-android-23-and.html?m=1) **Copy functionality in a WebView is available by default in Android 3.0 and above**, 
and may be this information may be help, [Android: how to select texts from webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview) 

**Edit** 
To Override text selection this post may help you 
[Override onLongTouch in a WebView, but keep text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/override-onlongtouch-in-a-webview-but-keep-text-selection)

Comment: OK,(available by default in Android 3.0 and above) but how can i override this default copy to use it in my code.