# Capturing text from an area in WebView

Tags: android

Say I draw a rectangle on top of an article rendered by a WebView. Let the two points on the screen: (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) represent the rectangle.

How can I obtain all the text within that rectangle in the WebView?

In other words, how can I associate a position on the screen to the word / html element in the underlying web page?

Comment: Do you want to select and copy text in webview?

Comment: You can take screenshot of the screen and then crop the part you want

Comment: @VicJordan: Yes I would like to copy the text.

Comment: To get selected text from webview in android check further links this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23979473/631803