# Selection text in WebView which created by service

Tags: android, webview, actionmode

How can `longclick` to select a text in `WebView` in a `Service`. I added a `WebView` by the `WindowManager`, when a url is loaded and a longclick to select text is done. The selected text is not visible and can not be selected.

How can I fix it ?

```
public class BtService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
public static final int WINDOW_EXPAND_FLAGS = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WINDOW_EXPAND_FLAGS, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    wv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    view.addView(wv);
    wv.loadUrl("https://tinhte.vn");

    windowManager.addView(view, params);
}}
```

Also this will require the android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.
When webview loaded, longclick in text to select text,-> action mode don't show

Comment: have you tried some thing yet? give your workaround.

Comment: i tried anything i know, action mode don't show.

Comment: Then show your code please, so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @alex , i added code

Comment: Have you tried this code? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29353049/1965084

Comment: This code use when webview inside a activity, not working with webview has created by service, Actionmode don't show

Comment: @HoaLe did you manage to solve this?