# Add custom selection menu on Android in React Native WebView

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I'm trying to show custom buttons for text selection in React-Native WebView on Android. I've created a custom component as described [here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Custom-Android.md). It works fine.
Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353049), I'm trying to override ActionMode with custom ActionMode.Callback to display my custom menu. However it doesn't seem to work at all.
My code:
CustomWebViewManager.java

```
protected static class CustomWebView extends RNCWebView {

    public Context context;

    public CustomWebView(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.context=context;
    }

    // setting custom action bar
    private ActionMode mActionMode;
    private ActionMode.Callback mSelectActionModeCallback;
    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    // this will over ride the default action bar on long press
    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
        ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return null;
        }
            String name = callback.getClass().toString();
            if (name.contains("SelectActionModeCallback")) {
                mSelectActionModeCallback = callback;
                mDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
                    new CustomGestureListener());
            }
        CustomActionModeCallback mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
        return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mActionMode = mode;
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
     //overriding onPrepareActionMode, onActionItemClicked and onDestroyActionMode as usual
       ...
    }

private class CustomGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                mActionMode.finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(mDetector !=null)
            mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


}
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Is that a correct approach?
Thanks.